# File download from server times out

Tags: php, curl, download

I have the following code timing out when I try to download some files from server

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

$source=array("landshop_formdata.sql","landshop_clientdata.sql","landshop_blogs.sql","landshop_counter.sql","landshop_hitems.sql");

$sourcepath = "http://www.landshoppe.com/";

$root = "C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www\Landshoppe/Downloaded Dbs/";

foreach($source as $bkup){
$source=$sourcepath.$bkup;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);

$destination = $root.$bkup;
$data = file_get_contents($source);
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
}
?>
```

What should be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid timeout issues, you can disable it by adding this line at the top of your server-side code :

```
set_time_limit(0); // no time limit
```

Or, you may set a timeout that is long enough to inform your user that something went wrong if nothing happend.

Comment: Thanks, Fred. Will try that out.

Comment: Thanks again, Fred. I have added the set_time_limit(0) line and worked like a charm !